# run a callback after an instance of a class-style object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, fingerprintjs2

I'm taking on someone else's code and not sure if I'm going about doing something the right way.

There's a Tracker 'class' (basically just an object of functions, including an 'initializer').

The class will make a call to a third party library.

A callback should happen after the results are returned.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
var tracker = Tracking.initialize({
        prod: 'OurProduct',
        requiredLayoutKeys: ["scr"],
        requiredInteractiveKeys: ["name", "action"],
        maxQueueSize: 5,
        timeToSend: 5000,
    });

// this code should happen in the callback once tracker is initialized:
InitSessionInfo(
    {sid: tracker.__sid, product: tracker.prod},
    function (returnObj) {
        setSessionIP(tracker.getIP(),function(returnObj){
            OurApp.auth(function (user) {
                OurApp.initialize(user);
            });
        });
    });
```

Here is what the Tracking object looks like in a separate file:

```
var Tracking = {
  __required_layout_keys: null,
  __required_interactive_keys: null,
  __maxQueueSize: null,
  __timeToSend: null,
  __initialized: false,

  initialize: function(config){
    Tracking.__initialized = true;
    Tracking.__required_interactive_keys = config.requiredInteractiveKeys;
    Tracking.__required_layout_keys = config.requiredLayoutKeys;
    Tracking.__maxQueueSize = config.maxQueueSize;
    Tracking.__timeToSend = config.timeToSend;
    Tracking.__bid = '';
    Tracking.__sid = '';
    Tracking.__ua = '';

    // get user data from FingerPrintJs2. 
    // The callback needs to happen after these results are returned: 
    new Fingerprint2().get(function(result, components){
        var ua = components.find(function(item){
            return item.key === "user_agent";
        });
        Tracking.__bid = result;
        Tracking.__sid = result + "." + Date.now();
        Tracking.__ua = ua.value;
    });
  },
 // there are other functions here that return ip, etc.
}
```

Unfortunately 'tracker' always comes back as undefined.

update:

when sticking a debugger here:

```
var tracker = Tracking.initialize({
    prod: 'OurProduct',
    requiredLayoutKeys: ["scr"],
    requiredInteractiveKeys: ["name", "action"],
    maxQueueSize: 5,
    timeToSend: 5000,
});

debugger;
```

the value of tracker is 'undefined' and the value of Tracking does not yet have its 'sid' value set.

Updates in Tracking:

```
var Tracking = {
 ...
 initialize: function(){
 ...
 return new Fingerprint2().get(function(result, components){
        var ua = components.find(function(item){
            return item.key === "user_agent";
        });
        Tracking.__bid = result;
        Tracking.__sid = result + "." + Date.now();
        Tracking.__ua = ua.value;
        return Tracking;
    });


 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, `fingerprintjs2` is (deep down in a series of internal function calls) returning a `setTimeout`, which is asynchronous by nature, but unfortunately you cannot chain off of by default. You can see, by looking at code inside the `setTimeout`, that it is invoking the function that you pass in to the `get()` function when the timeout has finished, so you can leverage that with promises to make sure things happen when they should.

What you have to do is wrap the `new Fingerprint2().get()` call with a promise, and then resolve that promise inside the "`done`" function (the one that gets called inside the setTimeout) that you pass into the `get` function.

Then, you can return the promise from the `initialize` function in your `Tracking` object so that you can chain off of it and perform actions after the data has been successfully initialized/updated.

[ES6 Promises & Chaining Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

[Working DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/5HQYLC?p=preview)

**ES6 Version using Promise object**

```
var Tracking = {
  __required_layout_keys: null,
  __required_interactive_keys: null,
  __maxQueueSize: null,
  __timeToSend: null,
  __initialized: false,
  initialize: function(config){
    Tracking.__initialized = true;
    Tracking.__required_interactive_keys = config.requiredInteractiveKeys;
    Tracking.__required_layout_keys = config.requiredLayoutKeys;
    Tracking.__maxQueueSize = config.maxQueueSize;
    Tracking.__timeToSend = config.timeToSend;
    Tracking.__bid = '';
    Tracking.__sid = '';
    Tracking.__ua = '';
    // get user data from FingerPrintJs2. 
    // The callback needs to happen after these results are returned: 
    // return the promise so we can chain
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        new Fingerprint2().get(function(result, components){
          var ua = components.find(function(item){
            return item.key === "user_agent";
          });
          Tracking.__bid = result;
          Tracking.__sid = result + "." + Date.now();
          Tracking.__ua = ua.value;
          resolve(Tracking); // resolve promise with updated Tracking obj
        });
    });
  },
  // there are other functions here that return ip, etc.
};

var tracker = null;
Tracking.initialize({
  prod: 'OurProduct',
  requiredLayoutKeys: ["scr"],
  requiredInteractiveKeys: ["name", "action"],
  maxQueueSize: 5,
  timeToSend: 5000,
}).then(function (updatedTracker) {
    tracker = updatedTracker;
    console.log(tracker);
});
```

**ES5 Compatible Version using $.Deferred()**

[jQuery Deferred Promise Docs](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/)

A small bit of the syntax changes here, but nothing drastic - and the idea is the exact same.

```
var Tracking = {
  __required_layout_keys: null,
  __required_interactive_keys: null,
  __maxQueueSize: null,
  __timeToSend: null,
  __initialized: false,
  initialize: function(config){
    Tracking.__initialized = true;
    Tracking.__required_interactive_keys = config.requiredInteractiveKeys;
    Tracking.__required_layout_keys = config.requiredLayoutKeys;
    Tracking.__maxQueueSize = config.maxQueueSize;
    Tracking.__timeToSend = config.timeToSend;
    Tracking.__bid = '';
    Tracking.__sid = '';
    Tracking.__ua = '';
    // get user data from FingerPrintJs2. 
    // The callback needs to happen after these results are returned: 
    var deferred = $.Deferred(); // create deferred object
    new Fingerprint2().get(function(result, components){
          var ua = components.find(function(item){
            return item.key === "user_agent";
          });
          Tracking.__bid = result;
          Tracking.__sid = result + "." + Date.now();
          Tracking.__ua = ua.value;
          deferred.resolve(Tracking); // resolve deferred object with updated Tracking obj
        });
    return deferred.promise(); // return deferred promise that we can chain off of
  },
  // there are other functions here that return ip, etc.
};

var tracker = null;
// jQuery deferreds work with $.when(promise).then() syntax
$.when(Tracking.initialize({
  prod: 'OurProduct',
  requiredLayoutKeys: ["scr"],
  requiredInteractiveKeys: ["name", "action"],
  maxQueueSize: 5,
  timeToSend: 5000,
})).then(function (updatedTracker) {
    tracker = updatedTracker;
    console.log(tracker);
});
```

Comment: hi @mhodges, after instituting your changes, I'm getting the error `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` on the `}).then(function (updatedTracker)` line.

Comment: @donaldduck Okay, give me a few minutes to try to debug it, I'll let you know what I find

Comment: @donaldduck Ohhh okay, I just looked at fingerprint's code. I see what they're doing. It's not actually asynchronous - it just looks like it at first glance. Their get function looks like so: `get: function (done) { ... return done(arg1, arg2)}`. What that means is that you simply need to return `Tracking` from the get function callback and you should be golden. I will update my post accordingly

Comment: @donaldduck Updated. Take a look

Comment: so it should look like `var tracker = Tracking.initialize({...}).then({callback})` ? I've instituted such a change (with `return Tracking` in the fingerprint method and still getting `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`.

Comment: @donaldduck No, remove the `.then()` see my updated answer

Comment: hi @mhodges, first of all, thanks very much for your help. It does seem to me that the code in fingerprint must be asynchronous. After putting a debugger after the `tracker = Tracking.initialize` function, I see that the value of tracker is still `undefined` and by the time the next function is read, the value of __sid is still not set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139180/discussion-between-donaldduck-and-mhodges).

Comment: Hi @mhodges, No, there are no return statements before `new Fingerpint2().get(...)`. Please see my update.

Comment: @donaldduck Okay! wow, sorry about this, but I finally figured it out. They were using a `setTimeout` deep in a function call chain internally that was throwing off the timing of everything. They are not using promises, unfortunately, so we have to do it ourselves. I have updated my post with what should be a working solution!

Comment: @donaldduck I also added an ES5 compatible version - let me know if either of these work for you! =)

Comment: Thanks so much for your really comprehensive guidance. The ES6 version suited me just fine and worked perfectly.

Comment: @donaldduck Absolutely! I'm glad I was able to help! Sorry for the initial confusion =)